# Passing data from Puppeteer to Vue JS Component

Tags: typescript, express, vuejs2, puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

The data flow of my app begins with a backend API request which launches a Vue component using puppeteer. Is there any way I can pass that data from Backend (express) to the vue component which is launched other than making the Vue component call a backend API to fetch data?

I have tried calling a backend API from the launched component but this seems to be a work-around rather than an actual solution.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Functions added to the `window` object through puppeteer's `exposeFunction` method can be called from within a Vue component to retrieve data from the backend.

For example, the puppeteer code (in an example where the backend API request contained the data `myData`):

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.exposeFunction('getRequestData', () => myData);
await page.goto("http://localhost/")
```

And the code you would put in Vue, to be executed when the component is mounted:

```js
this.data = await window.getRequestData();
```

Or if you need to get the types to compile in typescript:

```
this.data = await (window as unknown as { getRequestData: () => Promise<myDataType> }).getRequestData();
```

---

Another way to pass information from puppeteer to vue.js is through custom events and event listeners

For example, using vue3's composition syntax, the js part of a vue SFC could look like:

```js
const myData = ref<MyDataObject>()

window.addEventListener('custom:data', e => {
  myData.value = (e as CustomEvent).detail;
})
```

I believe this correlates to the following in vue2, although I'm unable to test this at the moment:

```js
...
data: {
  myData: undefined
}
...
mounted: function() {
  window.addEventListener('custom:data',e => {
    this.myData = (e as CustomEvent).detail;
  });
},
...
```

On the puppeteer side of things, send the event using the evaluate method:

```js
const myData = {} // data that express got from the initial backend API request
const page = await browser.newPage();
// any other configuration you need to do
await page.evaluate((data) => {
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('custom:data', {detail: data}));
}, myData)
```